# Stop selection of text in next span/div over in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**The issue**

I'm having a weird issue that I'd like to resolve. I have two spans which are next to each other in my code. When you select the last word in the first span, it will select the first word in the span next to it.

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/b7mybsLr/1/

**What I have tried**

Of the solutions I found online, the one which got me the closest was applying the CSS rule:

```
    user-select: all;
```

This stopped the issue, but instead created a new issue because when you click the text it highlights all the text in the span which isn't really what I want.

I've also tried adding:

```
    display: inline-block;
```

Which has also not helped, as seen in the demo.

I have also added '`&nbsp;`' to the end of each line, which actually does fix the issue. However, ideally this is code we'd like to avoid in our codebase.

And finally, I have tried swapping out the spans for divs, but as seen in the jsfiddle, the issue is still there. I'm not sure if this is a React issue in the way it renders the DOM, or if it is a CSS issue - thank you.

Comment: I don't see this issue in jsfiddle. Is it browser related

Comment: I can reproduce it if I double-click the last word. Probably default browser behaviour. Adding a space at the end does prevent it from happening. I think I would add that extra space myself if it were up to me. `text={"Test Span One" + " "}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the browser sees the text `One` and `Test` as a single piece of text. You can see this by removing the margin from the css. You will see the text `OneTest`

To fix this just add a space at the end of the TestComp text as in

```
<TestComp type={'span'} text={"Test Span One "} />
```

Or add your  to the end of the tag as in

```
<TestComp type={'span'} text={"Test Span One"} />&nbsp;
```

There are lots of ways to overcome it.